# How do I commit the contents of this symlink?

Tags: git, heroku, git-subtree

I have a Git repository with a shared folder and symlinks in subdirectories. If I try to push the contents of `site2` to Heroku, the bundle fails because  `shared` has no contents.

> website
>   --- shared
>   --- site1
>   --- site2
>   ------ shared (symlink to `../../shared`).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, as you probably found out, although Git is happy to store files that are themselves symlinks (barring some goofiness on Windows), Git doesn't store the *target* or the contents of the symlink. You need the *contents* of the shared folder in this repository as actual files.

If you can separate the shared folder to its own Git repository, you should be able to use [Git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) pretty easily (see Example 3).

> First, make the new repository wherever you want:
>
> ```
> $ <go to the new location>    
> $ git init --bare
> ```
>
> Back in your original directory:
>
> ```
> $ git subtree split --prefix=shared --annotate="(split)" -b split
> ```
>
> Then push the new branch onto the new empty repository:
>
> ```
> $ git push <new-repo> split:master
> ```

You should add/pull that subtree to the subdirectory now.

```
git subtree add --prefix site2/shared <split-remote> master
```

If you don't want to make a separate repository, you can probably **stop** after splitting and jump straight to the Subtree add and use the split branch from this repository.

```
git subtree add --prefix site2/shared origin split
```